# Add new colum to data based on first column record

Tags: linux

I have the following data:

```
Cow_ID  Age DIM MY  MCF MCP MCL Cow_Order
26  1424    0   NA  NA  0.0336  0.0505  
26  1425    1   NA  0.0404  0.0338  0.0505  
26  1426    2   NA  0.0388  0.0337  0.0505  
26  1427    3   NA  0.0391  0.0337  0.0505  
26  1428    4   35.2    0.0393  0.0337  0.0505  
35  1432    8   34.7    0.0396  0.0337  0.0505  
35  1433    9   33.6    0.0397  0.0337  0.0505  
35  1434    10  32.8    0.0397  0.0337  0.0505  
35  1435    11  33.7    0.0388  0.0337  0.0505  
47  1439    15  30.8    0.0391  0.0337  0.0505  
47  1440    16  31.3    0.0387  0.0337  0.0505  
47  1441    17  33.7    0.0392  0.0337  0.0505  
47  1442    18  30.2    0.0392  0.0337  0.0505  
47  1443    19  34.1    0.0393  0.0337  0.0505  
47  1444    20  33.3    0.0339  0.0286  0.0495
```

What I would like to do is to add an order from 1...1000 (in my complete data)into the column named Cow_Order based on first column cow_id: 
Final data should look like:

```
    Cow_ID  Age DIM MY  MCF MCP MCL Cow_Order
26  1424    0   NA  NA  0.0336  0.0505  1
26  1425    1   NA  0.0404  0.0338  0.0505  1
26  1426    2   NA  0.0388  0.0337  0.0505  1
26  1427    3   NA  0.0391  0.0337  0.0505  1
26  1428    4   35.2    0.0393  0.0337  0.0505  1
35  1432    8   34.7    0.0396  0.0337  0.0505  2
35  1433    9   33.6    0.0397  0.0337  0.0505  2
35  1434    10  32.8    0.0397  0.0337  0.0505  2
35  1435    11  33.7    0.0388  0.0337  0.0505  2
47  1439    15  30.8    0.0391  0.0337  0.0505  2
47  1440    16  31.3    0.0387  0.0337  0.0505  3
47  1441    17  33.7    0.0392  0.0337  0.0505  3
47  1442    18  30.2    0.0392  0.0337  0.0505  3
47  1443    19  34.1    0.0393  0.0337  0.0505  3
47  1444    20  33.3    0.0339  0.0286  0.0495  3
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a job for awk or gawk.

Comment: hi Gilbert I tried to search/think for this but could not find things I need. Can you pls give me some more hints. Thanks

Comment: @hieu how do you calculate `Cow_Order` column? I can't see much logic in there. Anyway, this task could be done with `awk` or any scripting language, like perl, php, python, etc.. Are you familiar with any of those?

Comment: @ pumbo: Cow_Order is just based on the column Cow_ID. You can see that first cow_ID is 26 and is repeated for some times, but they are the same cow, i mean first cow, the next apearance is 35 (with some repeats) --> 2nd cow and so forth. It is the same with counter, there is no logic
I just started linux as a job's requirement today so that I ask this trivival question. I hope you can help me out of this. In the mean time, I am still learning. Thanks

Comment: @hieu,is this data in database? or in file?

Comment: This is part of a file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do 'man awk' on any Linux system and you should get a new man page. While GNU's improved version is called gawk beginners may not see much difference between the two, though advanced people sure do.

```
generate | awk '
        /Cow_ID/ {print "\t" $0, "Cow_Order"; next;}
          { if ( $1 != Cow_last ) { 
               Cow_Order++;
               Cow_last = $1;
            }
            print $0, Cow_Order 
          }'
```

Look at awk's printf() function if you want to format into neat columns, or many other ways.

Answer (score 1):

if the data in a file with name testfile,try this:

```
count=1;for cow_id in `awk  '{if(FNR>1) print $1}' testfile |sort |uniq`; do awk -v cid=$cow_id -v orderid=$count '{if($1 == cid) {print $0"\t"orderid}} ' testfile; ((count++));done
```

the output:

```
26  1424    0   NA  NA  0.0336  0.0505          1
26  1425    1   NA  0.0404  0.0338  0.0505      1
26  1426    2   NA  0.0388  0.0337  0.0505      1
26  1427    3   NA  0.0391  0.0337  0.0505      1
26  1428    4   35.2    0.0393  0.0337  0.0505          1
35  1432    8   34.7    0.0396  0.0337  0.0505          2
35  1433    9   33.6    0.0397  0.0337  0.0505          2
35  1434    10  32.8    0.0397  0.0337  0.0505          2
35  1435    11  33.7    0.0388  0.0337  0.0505          2
47  1439    15  30.8    0.0391  0.0337  0.0505          3
47  1440    16  31.3    0.0387  0.0337  0.0505          3
47  1441    17  33.7    0.0392  0.0337  0.0505          3
47  1442    18  30.2    0.0392  0.0337  0.0505          3
47  1443    19  34.1    0.0393  0.0337  0.0505          3
47  1444    20  33.3    0.0339  0.0286  0.0495          3
```

Comment: @hieu,that's fine. please vote my answer, thank you!